# running the calculation code html table at application startup

Tags: javascript, html

I have tables in html in which I have rows (about 30)

I do mathematical calculations on them. Some of these calculations are saved to 'hidden colums' and later I have to smum them into the next fields.

normally I do something like this:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList;
  if (classList.contains('sth') || classList.contains('sth2') || classList.contains('sth3')) {

    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const [variable, variable2] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.variable,.variable2')];
    // do sth
  }
});
```

But now I need to call the code at the start of the application, and I tried to do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  table.(function (e) {

    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const [variable1, variable2, variable3] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.variable1,.variable2,.variable3')];

    if (variable3.selectedIndex == 17) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        variable1.value = onlyVar(variable2.value);
        function1();
        function2();
      }, 15);
    }
  });
});
```

But it does not work. How can I make sure that this code is executed?

**Notes:**

- It must check all the rows at system startup.
- Until now, it was checking the line in which the data was entered

Comment: There's no any event fired here, hence `e` is  not defined. You've to refer a row directly. And also unwrap the code from that function.